# Doubts in Initialization-on-demand holder idiom

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton, lazy-loading

Please refer to the link : [Initialization-on-demand holder idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom)

I have the following doubts :

1) When is a  inner static class initialized in java? Is it initialized at the same time as other static variables of the class? Or is it initialized on demand.

2) Is this pattern suitable to provide a singleton, thread safe access and lazy loading to a map/list. This map will hold the results of a heavy sql query. The access to this map needs to be singleton, thread-safe and the map should be initialized on demand.

3) What do these lines mean :

> However, the idiom is singleton-specific and not extensible to
>   pluralities of objects (eg a map-based cache).

Specifically :

> not extensible to pluralities of objects (eg a map-based cache).

Comment: "When is a static class initialized in java. Is it the same as static variables on class loading. Or is it initialized on demand." - what?

Comment: I have edited the mentioned lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something like that i suggest you to use [Double Checked Locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking).

A simple example:

```
package foo;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;


public class ExampleLazyLoad {

  private volatile ConcurrentMap<String, String> myExpensiveCache = null;


  public ConcurrentMap<String, String> getMyExpensiveMap() {
    if (myExpensiveCache == null) {
      synchronized (this) {
        if (myExpensiveCache == null) {
          final ConcurrentMap<String, String> newCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();
          // init the map
          myExpensiveCache = newCache;
        } // if
      } // synchronized
    } // if
    return myExpensiveCache;
  }

}
```

A static member of a class is initialized when the class is requested for the first time (beat me if i am wrong).

It always depends on what you really need. I am no real fan of singletons, but it always depends on the use case.

The code i posted is thread safe if you only use the `getMyExpensiveMap()` function to access the cache.